# audio.pause() is not working after audio.play() in React

Tags: reactjs, audio

I would like to make it so that if I press again after playing an audio, it will stop. However, audio.pause() is not responding.
Also, I tried to use `useCallback`, but that didn't work either.

```js
const [played, setPlayed] = useState(false)

const audio = new Audio(src)

const playMessage = () => {
  setPlayed(!played)
  if (played) {
    audio.pause()
    audio.currentTime = 0
  } else {
    audio.play()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you create new audio object every time you re-render. Can you try

```
const audio = useMemo(() => new Audio(src), [src]);
```